# What do four consecutive vertical lines mean?

Tags: syntax, rust

In the following code snippet:

```
let read_pool = ReadPool::new(
    "readpool",
    &Config::default_for_test(),
    || || Context {}
);
```

What are the four vertical lines `|| ||`?

Comment: Please give some context: where does this line come from? What is `ReadPool`?

Comment: Very useful for looking up unknown syntax in Rust: [the Rust Syntax Index](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/first-edition/syntax-index.html).

Answer (score 15):

`||` represents a lambda taking no arguments.

```
fn main() {
    let a = || println!("hello");
    let b = || { println!("world") };

    a(); // hello
    b(); // world
}
```

Two together is a lambda returning another lambda:

```
fn main() {
    let a = || || println!("hello world");

    let c = a();
    c(); // hello world
}
```

Comment: Finally i found the answer. `||` is kinda weird for an lambda tbh

Answer (score 7):

In Rust, `||` introduces a lambda (an unnamed function).

The arguments of the lambda are specified in between the two:

- `|a, b| a + b`: a lambda taking 2 arguments `a` and `b` and returning their sum,
- `|| println!("Hello, World")`: a lambda taking no argument and printing "Hello, World!".

Since the body of a lambda is just an expression, it can be another lambda:

- `|| || println!("Hello, World")`: a lambda taking no argument and returning a lambda taking no argument and printing "Hello, World!".

Therefore, `|| || Context {}` is simply:

- a lambda taking no argument and returning `|| Context {}`,
- which is a lambda taking no argument and returning an instance of `Context`.

Answer (score 3):

According to [that function's source](https://github.com/pingcap/tikv/blob/1a3f1badd17c50730132249a4408bb97970dfbfe/src/server/readpool/mod.rs#L56) this pattern is called a closure builder:

> // Rust does not support copying closures (RFC 2132) so that we need a
>   **closure builder**.
>
> // TODO: Use a single closure once RFC 2132 is
>   implemented.

The related code fragments reveal that this argument is [a function or closure](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Fn.html) returning another one, both without arguments (which `|| || Context {}` adheres to):

```
// src/server/readpool/mod.rs

pub fn new<F, CF>(name_prefix: &str, 
                  config: &Config, 
                  context_factory_builder: F // this is the argument in question
) -> Self where
    F: futurepool::Factory<CF>,
    CF: futurepool::Factory<T>

// src/util/futurepool.rs:

pub trait Factory<T> {
    fn build(&self) -> T;
}

impl<T, F> Factory<T> for F
    where F: Fn() -> T // a function taking no arguments
{
    fn build(&self) -> T {
        self()
    }
}
```